# multirow table, error

Tags: tables, multirow

I'm trying to create a table which some of the cells are `multirow` and this is my code:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\caption{""}
\label{table3}
\begin{tabular}{*{7}{|c}|}
\hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{H}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{K@10} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{K@20}\\\cline{2-7}
 & P & R & TFFR &  P & R & TFFR  \\\hline 
H\textsubscript{01}  & \multirow{2}{*} & \multirow{2}{*} & \multirow{2}{*} & \multirow{2}{*} & \multirow{2}{*}  & \multirow{2}{*}  \\\hline
H\textsubscript{02} & & & & & &  \\
H\textsubscript{03}  & \multirow{2}{*}  & \multirow{2}{*} & \multirow{2}{*} & \multirow{2}{*} & \multirow{2}{*}  & \multirow{2}{*}   \\\hline
H\textsubscript{04} & & & & & &  \\
H\textsubscript{05}  & \multirow{2}{*}  & \multirow{2}{*}  & \multirow{2}{*} & \multirow{2}{*} & \multirow{2}{*}  & \multirow{2}{*}  \\\hline
H\textsubscript{06} & & & & & &  \\\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I don't know what's wrong with this code. This is the error which I got:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.487 ... & \multirow{2}{*}  & \multirow{2}{*}  \\
```

Comment: `\multirow` takes three mandatory arguments: `rows`, `width`, and `text`. You consistently miss the third argument.

Comment: thanks, I don't want to have a text in my cell, I just want to have a colored cell, what should I do?

Comment: Use \multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor{<your color>}} with `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us list the errors first.

1. For quotation marks you shouldn't use `"..."` but ``` ``...'' ```
2. `\multirow{2}{*}{H}` takes three arguments - `\multirow{<rows>}{<width>}{<content>}`. You have missed the third argument. Even if you don't want to have text, you should have it but without content like `\multirow{2}{*}{}`.
3. `\textsubscript` isn't defined by LaTeX. You have to use `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` in the preamble to make it work. BTW are you trying to write a chemical formula? If so, there are packages meant for that job. Or are those `H\textsubscript{02}`s mathematical variables? Please elaborate.
4. To make colored cells, load `colortbl` package or `usepackage[table]{xcolor}` (Both are equivalent). and the use `\cellcolor{<color>` inside the cell:

   ```
   & \cellcolor{green!50!blue} <content> &
   ```

   or

   ```
    & \cellcolor{green!50!blue}\multirow{2}{*}{}  &
   ```
5. Do you really want vertical lines? What about reducing the number of some horizontal lines? You may read the documentation of `booktabs` package to learn how to produce a good table.

Now your code should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}    %% this in turn loads colortbl
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\caption{``''}
\label{table3}
\begin{tabular}{*{7}{|c}|}
\hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{H}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{K@10} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{K@20}\\\cline{2-7}
 & P & R & TFFR &  P & R & TFFR  \\\hline
H\textsubscript{01}  & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{}& \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*} {} & \multirow{2}{*}{}  \\\hline
H\textsubscript{02} & \cellcolor{green!50!blue} & & & & &  \\
H\textsubscript{03}  & \cellcolor{green!50!blue}\multirow{2}{*}{}  & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{}  & \multirow{2}{*}{}   \\\hline
H\textsubscript{04} & & \cellcolor{green!50!blue} & & & &  \\
H\textsubscript{05}  & \multirow{2}{*}{}  & \cellcolor{green!50!blue}\multirow{2}{*}{}  & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{}  & \multirow{2}{*}{}  \\\hline
H\textsubscript{06} & & & & & &  \\\hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you will have a perfect output in the PDF viewers at all zoom levels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\small
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\caption{``My caption''}
\label{table3}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}[vlines,colortbl-like]
\Hline
\Block{2-1}{H}      & \Block{1-3}{K@10} &&& \Block{1-3}{K@20} \\ \Hline
                    & P & R & TFFR &  P & R & TFFR \\ \Hline
H\textsubscript{01} \\ \Hline
H\textsubscript{02} & \cellcolor{green!50!blue}   \\
H\textsubscript{03} & \cellcolor{green!50!blue}   \\ \Hline
H\textsubscript{04} & & \cellcolor{green!50!blue} \\
H\textsubscript{05} & & \cellcolor{green!50!blue} \\\Hline
H\textsubscript{06} \\ \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of both codes]

If you prefer, it's possible to specify the colors of the cells in the `\CodeBefore`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\small
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\caption{``My caption''}
\label{table3}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}[vlines]
\CodeBefore
  \cellcolor{green!50!blue}{4-2,5-2,6-3,7-3}
\Body
  \Hline
  \Block{2-1}{H}      & \Block{1-3}{K@10} &&& \Block{1-3}{K@20} \\ \Hline
                      & P & R & TFFR &  P & R & TFFR \\ \Hline
  H\textsubscript{01} \\ \Hline
  H\textsubscript{02} \\ 
  H\textsubscript{03} \\ \Hline
  H\textsubscript{04} \\ 
  H\textsubscript{05} \\ \Hline
  H\textsubscript{06} \\ \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.